# C Logical operators on if statement OR AND

Tags: c, operators

Something is wrong with this logic it detects everything and prints `bad pkt detected`.

```
if((buff[0] != 0x0a || buff[0] != 0x0e) && (len == 210))
{
    printf("badpkt detected from %s\n", xpi);
} else {
    if(mysend(ssl_sd ? ssl_sd[i] : NULL, sd[i], buff, len) <= 0) MULTI_SKIP_QUIT
}
```

The logic is DENY all packets that are 210 in length. Except if the 1st byte is 0x0A or 0x0E.

This code is working though:

```
if((buff[0] != 0x0a) && (len == 210))
{
    printf("badpkt detected from %s\n", xpi);
} else {
    if(mysend(ssl_sd ? ssl_sd[i] : NULL, sd[i], buff, len) <= 0) MULTI_SKIP_QUIT
}
```

But I need both `0x0a` and `0x0e` to be the only 210 length packet allowed.

*edit*

What was I thinking, maybe its the lack of sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this logic:

```
if(buff[0] != 0x0a && buff[0] != 0x0e && len == 210)
```

With this condition:

```
 if((buff[0] != 0x0a || buff[0] != 0x0e) && (len == 210))
```

imagine `buff[0]` is `0x0e`. Then `buff[0] != 0x0a` will be true, which makes the whole sub expression `(buff[0] != 0x0a || buff[0] != 0x0e)` be true.

You could also invert the condition:

```
if((buff[0] == 0x0a || buff[0] == 0x0e) //always allow these
     || (len != 210)) //and allow anything thats not of length 210
{
    if(mysend(ssl_sd ? ssl_sd[i] : NULL, sd[i], buff, len) <= 0) 
         MULTI_SKIP_QUIT

} else {
     printf("badpkt detected from %s\n", xpi);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want both `0x0a` and `0x0e` allowed, you need to use this condition :

```
if((buff[0] == 0x0a || buff[0] == 0x0e) && (len == 210))
```

Answer (score 1):

This `(buff[0] != 0x0a || buff[0] != 0x0e)` is always **true**.

It should be `if(buff[0] != 0x0a && buff[0] != 0x0e && (len == 210))`